# Eclipse export runnable jar with main class inside a library jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I need to export a runnable jar from eclipse IDE. The launch configuration that I am giving has the main class from within the library jar.

From eclipse I am able to run that program.
But I want to export the project as runnable jar. But getting the error
"Could not find main method from the launch configuration".

How to export the jar which has main method from the library jar?

Note: if I export the jar with some other class and change the main class name as the one present inside the library jar, it works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your workaround is the only way to do it. Another workaround might be to create a main class in the enclosing project, which just calls the main class in the library.

Answer (score -1):

The correct way to export a runnable JAR from Eclipse is the following:

1) From the menu bar File menu -> Export;
2) Expand the Java node -> select Runnable JAR File -> Next;
3) In the Runnable JAR File Specification Page choose Java Applicaton launch configuration to create a runnable JAR;
4) In the Export destination field click Browse and select the location for exporting the JAR file.